# Fauxton errors in requre file

Tags: javascript, requirejs, couchdb, couchdb-futon, nosql

I installed CouchDB and it came with Fauxton. I can access it fine from:

```
http://localhost:5984/_utils/fauxton/#
```

I am using CoucbDB 1.6.1 (not sure how to find version number of Fauxton)

I am getting two JavaScript errors (both in require.js):

---

When I click on a database on the home screen, then select changes from the drop down menu in the top left:

```
TypeError: c.Views.Tabs is not a constructor
```

---

When I click the padlock next to a database on the home page (to set up permissions for that database - I haven't configured the admin user or anything yet but I imagine the site still isn't supposed to have a JavaScript error)

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

---

Neither pages are loading, what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: It is probably a CouchDB bug, I get the same errors in 1.6.0. You can still use the futon though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are bugs in the (for 1.x experimental) Fauxton which will get the new interface for 2.0. In favor of the CouchDB 2.0 release, the work on Fauxton for 1.x [is discontinued](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-dev/201408.mbox/%3CCAHdjipKdhqHq5yY0H3gZByVsbGxGYzhEZJkjyAokz5HUGkL3xw@mail.gmail.com%3E).